# how to show `<footer>` after last `<div>`?

Tags: html, css

How can I make `<footer>` display right after the last `<div>` without having to use `top`? It currently shows after the first `<div>`, which breaks the flow of the page.

```css
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
    overflow:auto;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}
 
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background:Red;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background:green;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background:blue;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background:yellow;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-5{
  background:orange;
}
 
.cd-scrolling-bg {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: black;
}

footer {
  height:100px;
  background:brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styleSO.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <main>
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
      
   </div> 
    <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
   <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
     <h1></h1>
   </div> 
  </main>

<footer><p>this is the footer</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that because the `main` element *overflows*, the `footer` gets placed immediately after the main element, ignoring that bit which is overflowing. What needs to happen is that the footer gets moved down to after the overflowed content.

We can use a float/clear combination to do this. By adding a floated pseudo-element to the end of the `main` element, and a clear declaration to the footer, the footer will be forced to be below the overflowed content. i.e. add

```
main:after { content:''; float:left;  }

footer { clear:left; }
```

So, in full,

```css
body, html, main {
  height:100%;
}

main { 
  display:block; /* for IE */
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
  overflow:auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
 
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background:Red;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background:green;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background:blue;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background:yellow;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-5{
  background:orange;
}
 
.cd-scrolling-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

main:after { 
  content:''; 
  float:left;
}

footer {
  clear:left;
  height:100px;
  background:brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styleSO.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
    </div> 
    <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
      <h1></h1>
    </div> 
    <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
      <h1></h1>
    </div> 
    <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
      <h1></h1>
    </div> 
  </main>
  <footer><p>this is the footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<main>
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">

</div> 
<div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2" >
</div> 
<div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-4">
  <h1></h1>
</div> 
<div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-5">
  <h1></h1>
</div> 
<div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
  <h1></h1>
</div> 
</main>
<footer><p>this is the footer</p>
</footer>
```

The footer goes inside the `body`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, @SuperVeetz. was a typo, `<footer>` is inside `<body>` in my original code. Still `<footer>` doesn't show at the end.

Answer (score 0):

not working

```
main div {
  height:100%;
}
```

try this

```
main div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

see more about

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/MaadMj

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
```

see what i did there, there are more solutions to than just this one, it could also be achieved with a fixed sticky footer(meh) or with margins.

I agreee, this fixed background layout is bit unflexible and unforgiving, cheers.